# Windows Terminal Services 2003 Remote Printer Printing One Blank Page

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing, windows-terminal-services

We've got a remote user on Windows XP with an HP Deskjet 6122 printer that is having some printing issues.  Weird thing is that the user was able to print before but now all of a sudden cannot.  There have been no changes or updates to the workstation nor the terminal server.  When she tries to print she only gets one blank page regardless of the application she is printing from.  Checking the server logs we can see were the printer gets set for the session and where the print job is sent to her local printer.  Also, no other users are having printing problems at this time.

We have already attempted a server reboot, had her reinstall her print drivers, and have also reinstalled the printer drivers on the terminal server.  None of these actions have resolved the issue and I am running out of ideas.  Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ensured that the spool and temp directories are free of any possible "stranded" files?

Comment: The directories are empty.

Comment: That is on the print server, right? What's the chkdsk condition of the print server as well?

Answer (score 0):

Can you identify the print processor used?  Have seen HP printers that use the HP Print Processors give issues.  And the issue seems random.  Note teh settings used now to allow you to easily revert if chnage does not help. Try changing Print Processor to WinPrint and data type to RAW and see if that helps.

Comment: I went to the client machine and checked the settings and they were already set to WinPrint and RAW.  I ran a test print from the terminal server and I see the job is spooled on the server then it spools on the client machine.  However the local printer only spits out a blank page.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What happens when you initiate a "test page" on the print server?